# Limiting captured range in RegEx expression

Tags: javascript, regex

(Note: the following is using javascript flavored RegExen, in which . does not match newline, but [^] does.)

Imagine I have this text:

`chaff more chaff START PATTERN more chaff
chaff more chaff START PATTERN juicy stuff
juicy stuff juicy stuff END PATTERN chaff
chaff START PATTERN more juicy stuff more
juicy stuff END PATTERN`

... and I want a RegEx with a global flag (g) that captures the juicy stuff.  Specifically, I want the first match to be

`START PATTERN juicy stuff
juicy stuff juicy stuff END PATTERN`

and the second match to be

`START PATTERN more juicy stuff more
juicy stuff END PATTERN`

The fly in the ointment is that first START PATTERN.  I've spent some time in regex101.com (an awesome tool for those that don't know it), and this one does not work:

```
/(?:START PATTERN[^]+)?(START PATTERN[^]+END PATTERN)/?
```

It captures the second group ("more juicy stuff") but not the first.  I've also tried various combinations of negative lookahead, but without success.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a [tempered greedy token](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed):

```
START PATTERN(?:(?!(?:START|END) PATTERN)[^])*END PATTERN
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jQ4wO5/1).

The `(?:(?!(?:START|END) PATTERN)[^])*` is called a tempered greedy token because the greedy `*` quantifier is tempered with a negative lookahead. Inside the lookahead we list all the patterns that we do not want to match up to the trailing delimiter.

Note you can add more precision by adding word boundaries if you plan to match literal words `START` and `END`:

```
\bSTART PATTERN\b(?:(?!\b(?:START|END) PATTERN)[^])*\bEND PATTERN
```

Note that to make it more efficient, we can *unroll* it:

```
START PATTERN[^ES]*(?:S(?!TART PATTERN)[^ES]*|E(?!ND PATTERN)[^ES]*)*END PATTERN
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/jQ4wO5/3)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: Thank you. I have noticed now it can gobble more without that (though SND PATTERN is unlikely to be present in the string IMHO :)).

Comment: No, but `START PATTERN[^ES]*(?:S(?!TART PATTERN)[^S]*)*` can match "START PATTERN abcd Sefgh END PATTERN".

Comment: I see, the main issue with that is that the expression would fail to match the *minimal window* between the delimiters.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I bow before your RegEx prowess, and thank you for the link to http://www.rexegg.com/.  Great answer.